# How to show color emoji?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am developing one window based application with the help of Java-FX and i want show colorful emoji but I am able to show black and white emoji with the help of Segoe UI Emoji font but how to show colorful emoji with this font.

```
package study;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Study extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());


        VBox root = new VBox();     

        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();         
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setContent(browser); 
webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation(this.getClass().getClassLoader().
getResource("study/application.css").toString());
 webEngine.loadContent("<html><body>Testing <p>&#128560;</p></body></html>");


        root.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane);
        scene.setRoot(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "colorful?" You can use CSS to set the color of a font (and everything else) in JavaFX. However, if you are looking for multi-color emoji, that cannot be done with simple text.

Comment: Hi @Zephyr, I want to show color emoji ( ) like whatsapp has.

Comment: You cannot do so with a font; you'll need to use images instead.

Comment: The same html code is working fine with browser. so that you mean we can't achieve this by the javafx desktop application.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your `application.css` file.

Comment: p {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Emoji";
  src: url(seguiemj.ttf);
}

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but I believe it's the web browser that actually displays the colorful emoji. The font itself does not contain any color information. When using the unicode to display an emoji with HTML, your browser determines what that is going to look like. In JavaFX, I do not believe this is possible and you'll need to use images.

Comment: Hi, So other developer have some other solution? Or should I accept @zephyr answer?.